# Catch and diagnose Plotly.js exception

Tags: javascript, error-handling, plotly.js

I'd like to catch and diagnose an issue with a Plotly.js chart spec that generates an exception deep in the stack trace like below.

The error in this case seems to happen when the chart is sized such that Plotly.js sizes the data labels on the bars too small.  I'm not saying this is a good aesthetic chart design on our part.

But what's puzzling is the error isn't getting caught by either the `.catch()` method or the `try..catch` block.  How do I catch the error?

The other puzzle is the chart draws fine.  How do I identify tolerable exceptions like this vs `oops-the-graph-fails-to-draw` errors?

```
try {
    Plotly.newPlot($chartDiv[0], data, layout, options).then(_.noop).catch(_.noop)
} catch (e) {}
```

#### Stack trace

[image]

### Example image

[image]

Comment: i'm guessing it logs as an error but continues fine (and doesn't end in your catch) because the plotly api catches the error, logs it and then returns instead of throwing since it wasn't critical to the graph rendering

Comment: @Jon  your comment is the correct answer